# Why my code throws "could not find function" error but the help file for the function is accessible?

Tags: function, package

A function I have used repeatedly in the past is now not working. It's the `update.meta` function which I believe is part of the robumeta package. I'm getting a message that the function can't be found when I tried to use the following code:

`update.meta(m.gen_PPConly, subgroup = content, tau.common = FALSE)`

I've checked that the package robumeta is installed. RStudio gives a message that it's been successfully unpacked.

I've put in library (robumeta) to try and ensure it is loaded.

It's weird to me that although I'm getting the message that the function can't be found, when I put in help (update.meta), information about it comes straight up. Is that normal if the package isn't loaded?

This worked consistently for weeks and all of sudden, I'm getting this error.